# Gnuplot for loop output

Tags: gnuplot

I have two different text files which have a data column and a value column each. Ĩ wanted to plot both using a 'plot for' loop but I wanted to changed the name of the output to match the file I'm plotting. Right now my code looks like this:

```
set terminal postscript eps color
set out "test.eps"
set size 0.6
set multiplot
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m"
set format x "%b\n%y"
set xtics "2004-01", 12*2629746, "2016-12"
filenames = 'ArcheryData.txt CanyoningData.txt'
plot for [file in filenames] file u 1:2 w l title file
```

What I get now is the test.eps file which has the two data files plotted in the same graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case, you might use the `do` loop as:

```
set terminal postscript eps color
set size 0.6

set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m"
set format x "%b\n%y"
set xtics "2004-01", 12*2629746, "2016-12"

do for [ name in "ArcheryData CanyoningData" ]{
    set output name.".eps"
    plot name.".txt" u 1:2 w l title name
}
```

Alternatively, the variable `name` could be specified when invoking Gnuplot, thus with a script as:

```
set terminal postscript eps color
set size 0.6

set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m"
set format x "%b\n%y"
set xtics "2004-01", 12*2629746, "2016-12"

set output name.".eps"
plot name.".txt" u 1:2 w l title name
```

one might then use it as `gnuplot -e "name='ArcheryData';" fig.gpl`